# The right way of using a variable - inside or outside a function loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I was making a loop when suddenly got hit by a question.
Which is supposed to be "the right way":

```
    // code.. 
    $('tr','#my_table').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var show_id = $(this).attr('data-show-id');
            // code..
            // code..
        });
    });
    // code..
```

OR

```
    // code.. 
    var show_id = 0; /* HERE */ 
    $('tr','#my_table').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            show_id = $(this).attr('data-show-id');
            // code..
            // code..
        });
    });
```

In the first example I create for each `tr` a new variable `show_id`.
In the second I use the same global `show_id` for all of the `tr`'s in the table and I repopulate it on each tr.

So the question wold be: REGARDLESS of the programing language - Is it better practice to create on each loop a new variable which be released when the function exits or "catch" the memory for the entire run and avoid recreating a variable each time?

Comment: I believe you are supposed to define it first, then use it in the code later.

Comment: Unrelated to what you asked, you don't need that `.each()` at all. You can say `$('tr','#my_table').click(function() { ... });`

Comment: @nnnnnn aware of that. Needed to make my example clear.. Thnx for the clarification.

Comment: I don't think we can really disregard the programming language here. In C++, for example, if the variable contains an instance of a user-defined class whose constructor and/or destructor is costly to run, then you will definitely want to put it in the outermost scope you can manage. But in, say, Javascript, it won't make any difference most of the time.

Comment: It's good to create the variable outside, if you are using it for sharing datas between multiple event handlers.

Comment: Regarding your actual question, I'd declare the variable inside the function. Though it would help to see what else is in that function, because e.g., I don't like declaring variables that are only used once after their value is set - maybe you don't even need the variable...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable is not created during the loop. It is needed in the event handler only, which will be executed on its own. Moving the variable (when it's only needed inside) outside has three problems:

- access to a higher-scoped variable is a littlebit slower
- garbage collection does not collect the value (not memory-efficient)
- possible trouble when async behavior in the event handler accesses the variable but the handler is invoked multiple times

The second point is also the answer to your question:

> Is it better practice to create on each loop a new variable which be released when the function exits or "catch" the memory for the entire run and avoid recreating a variable each time?

It hardly makes sense to waste the memory for the entire time, creating the function scope is fast. Moving the declaration away from the use of the variable can be considered bad practise, moving it to a different scope even can introduce errors.

Preallocating the memory would make sense if you run on a machine with big memory, and creating/deleting the object (that stays constant for all handlers) is slow.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends, really, on where you need that variable to exist. JS will hoist the variable to the top of the current scope (the one in which is was declared) or create an (evil) global if the var wasn't declared.

It doesn't really matter if you declare a var inside a loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var j = 1*2;
}
```

is translated into:

```
var i, j;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    j = 1*2;
}
```

A couple of *"rules of thumb"*, though:

- if you're using a global variable, you're probably making a mistake
- if you're declaring a variable inside a loop, you probably don't need that variable anyway
- if you're not declaring variables, try doing this with your script:

---

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    //your code here
}());
```

And debug it until you're implied-global-free.

In your example, you're "offering" the choice between `show_id` being declared in the global scope (well, `$(document).ready(callback` scope anyways), or inside the `click` handler. There's nothing to prevent you from declaring the variable in the `each` callback either, which wouldn't make much difference in this case, but that's a different matter.

In JS, functions all have their own scope, and you declare a variable in the scope you need it.

Having said that, and just noticing your *performance* tag, your code is about as bad as it gets in terms of efficiency. Instead of looping over the rows, and binding event handlers all over: **delegate** the event:

```
$('#my_table').on('click','tr',function(e)
{
    var show_id = e.target.attr('data-show-id');
});
```

In this code, `show_id` will be GC'ed after the click handler has returned, if you want the `show_id` to be preserved, for example, to check when the next row is clicked:

```
$('#my_table').on('click','tr',(function (show_id)
{
    return function(e)
    {
        console.log('show_id was: ' + show_id);
        show_id = e.target.attr('data-show-id');
        console.log('and is now: ' + show_id);
    };
}()));
console.log(show_id);//undefined
```

The variable is kept in scope (the function wrapped around the `return function` is the scope in which `show_id` as declared, but its return value references that variable, so it's not GC'ed. Outside that returned function, we're in a higher scope, so we can't access the variable at all. What we *can* do is expose its value:

```
var someVar = {};
$('#my_table').on('click','tr',(function (show_id)
{
    return function(e)
    {
        show_id = e.target.attr('data-show-id');
        someVar.myTableClicks = show_id;
        console.log(someVar.myTableClicks);//value of show_id
    };
}()));
console.log(someVar.myTableClicks);//undefined
//after a couple of clicks
console.log(someVar.myTableClicks);//some value
```

Now, we can access the value of `show_id` anywhere we can access `someVar`.

Personally, I prefer to keep group code that require some variable to be available:

```
var access = (function(timer)
{
    var speed = 100,
    begin = function(callback, interval)
    {
        speed = +(interval) || speed;
        timer = setInterval(callback, speed);
    },
    stop = function()
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
    return {start: start, stop: stop};
}());
```

In this example, both the `start` and `stop` functions require access to the `timer` var, but I don't want any code from outside to mess with `timer`'s value, so I'm only exposing those functions. AFAIK, the callback argument function can contain `timer` or `speed` references, but they won't reference the `speed` and `timer` vars I'm trying to shield, because the callback function will, by definition be declared in another scope, and therefore it *can't* have access to this scope. Even so, if you want to be *absolutely* sure, you can always do this:

```
var access = (function(timer)
{
    var speed = 100,
    begin = function(callback, interval)
    {
        speed = +(interval) || speed;
        timer = (function(timer, speed)
        {//masks timer & speed from the higher scope
            return setInterval(callback, speed);
        }('abc', 'def'));//assign dummy values
        timer = setInterval(callback, speed);
    },
    stop = function()
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
    return {start: start, stop: stop};
}());
```

Comment: But in the OP's example it's either in a function or not. The declaration won't be hoisted out of the function...

Comment: @nnnnnn: No, but that's why I said: to the top of the current scope.

Comment: Yes. So what I'm saying is that you didn't really cover the case the OP set out.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I've added a lot more info, and more specific info, relevant to the OP's question. seeing as he tagged the question _performance_ I also suggested delegating the event, rather than binding individual handlers

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirements.

**First example:**

```
$('tr','#my_table').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var show_id = $(this).attr('data-show-id');
            // code..
        });
    });
```

Variable is **local** and can be used inside anonymous function binded with .each or click.

**Second Example:**

```
var show_id = 0; /* HERE */ 
    $('tr','#my_table').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            show_id = $(this).attr('data-show-id');
            // code..
            // code..
        });
    });
```

Here the variable is **Global** and thus its scope is valid in the entire script!!!

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I would use:

```
    $("tr","#my_table").each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
             var $this = $(this);                
             var show_id = $this.data("show-id");
            // code..
            // code..
        });
    });
```

1. Use on("click", function() {...}); instead of .click()
2. var $this = $(this) is recommended in case you will use it further down in your code else you can ignore it
3. show_id in this case will not be accessible outside of this scope.
4. To acces data-* atributes you should use data("-*") instead of attr("-*")

Comment: Regarding your point 4, remember that if you use `.data()` to access `data-` attributes jQuery will attempt to guess the datatype of the value and do a conversion, so you might not get back what you were expecting. `.attr()` returns the string as is. Regarding point 1, could you add an explanation as to why you recommend that?

Comment: Also check @nnnnnn's comment at the question about `each`

Comment: I prefer to use on and off because I find it more intuitive when binding/unbinding events to objects, not to mention that .click will call on("click", ...

Answer (score 0):

Memory for all of the variables will be allocated at the entrance of a method, so that the two examples are equivalent. The second example is better because it will be more secure because of the limited scope for variables (will not accidentally use a variable outside the loop).

Comment: The examples are *not* equivalent since there are **3** method entrances.

Comment: _"Memory for all of the variables will be allocated at the entrance of a method"_ - Are you saying that when the outer function begins the JS environment allocates memory for variables in the inner function? Why would it do that when the inner function may never be called? How can it do that given that (not in the OP's code, but more generally) the inner function could be recursive?